# To verify Group Policy settings (GPedit.msc) on different Windows servers using powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, group-policy, gpo

I am trying to automate this process by using powershell. When i run the script it should search on different windows server's Group Policy Settings and verify whether they are valid or not !!

Currently to extract the data i am running : Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\rsop\computer -Query "select * from RSOP_SecuritySettings"

But I am not able to find some policies when i execute that query. For example i am looking for a policy "store passwords using reversible encryption" under Password Policy. Because once i get this details i can use the policy keyname and setting to query on different servers.

All i want to say or know is why i am not able to extract some policies even though i can see them on my computer(GPedit.msc). If some know the answer could you please guide me to query how to get all the policy settings

Comment: Are you retrieving *User* or *Computer* policies?

Comment: computer policies @t

Comment: I figured something here. I have tried another script : Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\rsop\computer -List -Class RSOP*  . Now i am able to get all the class names under RSOP. I think i will check in all those class names whether i can find any thing what i am looking for . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to extract them because those are disabled/not defined in the dev/prod domains. Using the Proper class name now i am able to retrieve all the settings which are defined. Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\rsop\computer -Query "select * from ClassName". Now by defining these settings in my local computer i am able to compare on different servers. It worked. Let me know if anyone have questions.